# Laravel : Update field when value is exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with updating file. I have a form with the following attributes :

- title
- text
- pdf file

The problem is the update operation will save the pdf file as the following value :

- with file : **["example.pdf"]**
- no file : **[""]**

It will include **[""]** to the pdf file value when updated.

I want the pdf file updated to a new file when a new file is selected, old file remained when there is no new file selected and null value to file when there is no file, to begin with.

Here is the update controller.

```
public function update()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;    
        $main_id = Input::get('edit_id');
        $announcements = Announcement::find($main_id);
        $getFile = Input::file('new_brochure');

        $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
      }

      if ($getFile) {
        $file = array('new_brochure' => Input::file('new_brochure'));
        $destinationPath = 'img/brochures/announcements'; // upload path
        $extension = Input::file('new_brochure')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
        Input::file('new_brochure')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $announcements->brochure = $fileName;
    }

    $old = Announcement::where('id',$main_id)->pluck('brochure');
    if (empty($old)) {
        $announcements->brochure = null;
    }
    else {
        $announcements->brochure = $old;
    }

    $announcements->title = (Input:: get('title'));
    $announcements->from = (Input:: get('from'));
    $announcements->to = (Input:: get('to'));
    $announcements->text = (Input:: get('text'));
    $announcements->is_active = '1';
    $announcements->created_by = $user_id;
    $announcements->updated_by =  $user_id;
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $announcements->created_at = $current_date.".000";
    if ($announcements->save()){
        $this->request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Updated successfully!');
    }
    else{
         $this->request->session()->flash('alert-warning', 'Could not update!');
        }
        return redirect()->route('Announcements_view');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this code? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$old = Announcement::where('id',$main_id)->pluck('brochure');
```

To:

```
$old = Announcement::where('id',$main_id)->value('brochure');
```

The thing is `pluck()` will return a collection of `brochure`, not a string. And `value()` will return a string or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;    
            $main_id = Input::get('edit_id');
            $announcements = Announcement::find($main_id);
            $getFile = Input::file('new_brochure');

            $rules = array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required',
            );

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
          }

          if (!empty(Input::file('new_brochure'))) {
            $file = array('new_brochure' => Input::file('new_brochure'));
            $destinationPath = 'img/brochures/announcements'; // upload path
            $extension = Input::file('new_brochure')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
            Input::file('new_brochure')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $announcements->brochure = $fileName;
        }
        else

            $old = Announcement::where('id',$main_id)->value('brochure');
            $announcements->brochure = $old;
        }

        $announcements->title = (Input:: get('title'));
        $announcements->from = (Input:: get('from'));
        $announcements->to = (Input:: get('to'));
        $announcements->text = (Input:: get('text'));
        $announcements->is_active = '1';
        $announcements->created_by = $user_id;
        $announcements->updated_by =  $user_id;
        $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $announcements->created_at = $current_date.".000";
        if ($announcements->save()){
            $this->request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Updated successfully!');
        }
        else{
             $this->request->session()->flash('alert-warning', 'Could not update!');
            }
            return redirect()->route('Announcements_view');
        }
    }
```

Comment: first of all, how is this different from the first answer, second please don't just answer with a code

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bhaskar

Comment: For first, you can check how is different from first answer. Thanks for give me good suggestion, But  90% coders only see code. Not read any comment. @My name is jeff

Comment: @Bhaskar  you see i said how its different from the first answer because you didn't say what you have changed, and no coders don't only see the code because thats just retarded

Comment: @Bhaskar and Code only answer can get you alot of downvotes

Comment: @my name if jeff You are right for get only string value of brochure field. But here iman don't want to save null value when he will not upload new file. So i just correct him code for set old value or new value.

Comment: @my name is jeff I don't know that. i am new on stackoverflow. thanks jeff. I will remember it for my every answer.

Comment: @Bhaskar its okay, but next time remember always put explanations on your code and why you did that and stuff like that so you don't get vote downs